# Reneme files in R - Delete a section of the name

Tags: r

I have several files in a folder, named:

```
cbf485_f_p1_Reflection__4__29.txt

cbf485_f_p2_Reflection__2__32.txt

cbf4166_m_p2_Reflection__1__41.txt

nkm2801_m_p6_Reflection__4__139.txt
```

and so on.

I want to erase the last part of the name from each file, obtaining:

```
cbf485_f_p1_Reflection__4.txt

cbf485_f_p2_Reflection__2.txt

cbf4166_m_p2_Reflection__1.txt

nkm2801_m_p6_Reflection__4.txt
```

using R. R is life.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that you want to rename the files themselves, or just change the string representations in the R session?

Comment: `mapply(file.rename, filenames, sub("__\\d+\\.", ".", filenames))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapply(file.rename, filenames, sub("__\\d+\\.", ".", filenames))`

Comment: Thanks for posting as an answer. [Relevant meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment).